# how to add properties intellisense in vscode

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, nativescript, intellisense

I have a custom button component and This is how I'm using it in my React native project

```
<ButtonPressable
  text="Login"
  borderRadius="20"
  alignSelf="stretch"
  svg={RightArrowSvg}
/>;
```

Here, `text`,`svg` and 18 other properties are there. And currently I'm writing all the properties by referring to the cheat sheet which I wrote.

Is there any why to add intellisense to vscode so that when I press `alt+enter` It should show all the 18 properties The custom component have.

Comment: Not sure with JS. you could use TS which is entirely for that.

Comment: @senthilbalaji I'm not interested in ts and It's possible with JS. I have used in other technology like Navtivescript where they have intellisense plugin which do that.

Comment: look at react proptypes, there you can define the accessible properties - by adding intellisense to your VSCode this should add "autocompletion" or "suggestion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `React Prototypes`

Just exactly follow this step

- Add this at the top of your component file

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/**
@extends {React.Component<ButtonPressable.protoTypes>}
*/
```

- Add this after class at bottom or wherever you fell prettier but outside class `ButtonPressable`

```
ButtonPressable.protoTypes = {

  /** text to be displayed on button */
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

  /** changes text color */
  color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

}
```

That's it, Know you can access these props with description by pressing `ctrl + space`

Comment: React is vast without proper route ! Thank you for the answer.